# Do I need to validate the apiKey or is validating the user's auth enough for an HTTPS callable function?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to define a cloud function that I can run from both the client and the backend. I know from the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) that an HTTPS callable function will automatically include user `auth` data. Is it enough to do the `auth` check below? Or do I need to do extra stuff like check to see if `context.auth.uid` exists in my `users` collection (where I've saved a list of users and their `uid`'s)?

Also, do I need to validate an API key? I'm trying to plan for the worst so I assume that a malicious user will somehow be able to pass this up themselves, so not sure how important it is to check this.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp();

interface Data {
  apiKey: string;
}

export const getServerTimestamp = functions.https.onCall(async (data: Data, context) => {
  try {
    // Check if the user is authenticated
    if (!context.auth) {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unauthenticated', 'The user is not authenticated');
    }

    // Validate the request
    if (data.apiKey !== 'MY_API_KEY') {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError('permission-denied', 'The API key is invalid');
    }

    const timestamp = admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
    return { timestamp };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'An error occurred', error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing `if (!context.auth)` is sufficient to check that the user calling the CloudFunction is declared in the Firebase Auth service of your project and is authenticated.

HOWEVER note that it is very easy for a malicious user to get your project API key and create an account (email/password) in the Auth Service via the Auth REST API. So indeed you should check that the user is either present in your ˋusers` collection (which shall be protected against free document creation), or, better, assign Custom Claims to the (genuine) users.

If `context.Auth` is not null (or undefined) you can be sure the user is authenticated against your Firebase project, so IMO you don’t need to add an API key check. As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users#auth_tokens): "The Firebase ID tokens "are signed JWTs that securely identify a user **in a Firebase project**."

---

**A last remark**: You indicate that you "want to define a cloud function that (you) can run from both the client and the backend".

A Callable Cloud function is not the easier Cloud Function to call from "the" backend, wether it is another Cloud Function or a server you own. You don’t detail how you want to call this Cloud Function but if you want to call it via an HTTPS request you’ll need to follow a [complex protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference) .

Comment: To your last point - it doesn't need to be complicated. I just wanted a single way to write the server timestamp when the client (i.e. the user when using the app) is writing a record and when my Firestore triggers write a record. I figured if I use the same cloud function to do this, then this would achieve what I'm looking for. But if there is an easier way I'm all ears!

Comment: If I correctly understand your requirement, why don't you write a [background triggered Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_when_a_new_document_is_created) which is triggered any time a user creates (and/or update?) a Firestore document and which saves the timestamp.

Comment: Ah yes that's another good option. After doing some research, apparently there's a way to get a "sentinel" value of the server time on the client set using `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`. I'm just going to do it this way. I appreciate your help though!